# Understanding probability of order of events with playing card example

Tags: probability

I have a deck of card. What is the probability of coming king of heart,  queen of spade, and ace of diamond

1. in order
2. in any order

I have to solve the above problem when I put the card back to deck(with replacement) or when I just pick the cards (without replacement)

In order(with replacement)

1/52 * 1/52 * 1/52

In order(without replacement)

1/52 * 1/51 * 1/50

In any order(with replacement)

3/52 * 2/52 * 1/52

In any order(without replacement)

3/52 * 2/51 * 1/50

Am I correct for above solutions?

If no, please provide the correct solution.

If yes, then what would be correct way of doing it? I mean is there any direct formula to solve it? So I can apply it in case of large space or I can automize it.

Comment: The answers are all correct.

Comment: Is there any direct formula to do that? I did it manually.

Comment: For the small number $3$ of cards involved, your procedures are the most efficient. One can use the same basic reasoning to obtain general formulas. If no one has answered in the next couple of hours, I will write down something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the small number ($3$) of cards involved,  you have found the *answers*, correctly, in what I think is the most concrete and efficient way. For *solutions*, it would be good to have some verbal explanation to accompany the answers. The reasoning that led you to the expressions, though clear to any experienced reader, should, at least in part, be made explicit.

We look at a slightly more general problem. We have a deck of $n$ distinct cards. A *sequence* $C_1,C_2,\dots, C_k$ of $k$ distinct cards is specified. (In your problem, $k=3$, and the sequence is $\heartsuit$ K, $\spadesuit$ Q, $\diamondsuit$ A.)

We ask for the probability of obtaining the sequence if we sample from the deck (i) with replacement and (ii) without replacement.

We also ask for the probability of obtaining the cards in the sequence, in any order, if we sample (iii) with replacement and (iv) without replacement.

(i) Since we are sampling with replacement, all sequences of $k$ cards are *equally likely*. There are $n^k$ such sequences. Only $1$ of them, namely $C_1,C_2,\dots, C_k$ is *favourable*. So the probability we obtain this sequence is $\frac{1}{n^k}$.

(ii) There are $n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)$ sequences of $k$ cards,and all these sequences are equally likely.  Again, only $1$ of them is favourable. So the probability we obtain this sequence is $\frac{1}{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots (n-k+1)}$. This can be rewritten more compactly as $\frac{(n-k)!}{n!}$.

To justify the count $n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots (n-k+1)$, note that the first card can be chosen in $n$ ways. For each of these ways, there are $n-1$ ways to pick the second card. So there are $n(n-1)$ ways to pick the first $2$ cards. For each of these ways, there are $n-2$ ways to pick the third card, so there are $n(n-1)(n-2)$ ways to pick the first $3$ cards. Continue.

(iii) We will be happy if we obtain the cards in the given sequence $C_1,C_2,\dots,C_k$, in *any order*. These $k$ cards can be permuted in $k!$ ways, so there are $k!$ favourables. In the sampling with replacement case, the probability we will be happy is therefore $\frac{k!}{n^k}$.

(iv) In the no replacement case, the sample space, as we saw in (ii), has $\frac{(n-k)!}{n!}$ elements, and, as in (iii), there are $k!$ favourables. So the probability we will be happy is $\frac{k!(n-k)!}{n!}$.

We look at the same problem from a somewhat different point of view. There are $\binom{n}{k}$ equally likely $k$-card "hands," since there are $\binom{n}{k}$ ways to **choose** $k$ cards from $n$ distinct cards. Thus the probability we will be happy is $\frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}}$.

Comment: I think I asked a question in very advanced. I should have finished permutation & combination first.

Comment: As I mentioned, your calculations were fine, and showed a good intuition for the problem. My answer pushed a little beyond.